# What is the best solution to retrieve large recordsets - more than 3000 rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008, pagination

I have a SQL Server table with 3000 rows in it. When I retrieve those rows it is taking time using a Select Statement. What is the best solution to retrieve them?

Comment: How are you currently doing it? Perhaps once you've noted your query people could help you optimize it. More details are required to help you efficiently.

Comment: Definitely isn't enough info here.  3000 records is not a big ask if you ask for them in the right way.  Please post your query and if possible, your schema.

Comment: i have written normally select statement in Storeprocedure and calling that Storeprocedure .And i need to in GridView as Paging

Comment: You just gave the solution to your question kumar ;) paging

Comment: but it is taking time to retrive those records

Comment: Please post the script and the stored proc.

Comment: Sure, paging takes time. Though, loading all in one step takes more time ;-). Best solution, in my opinion, is not to load 3k rows into a GUI control. I know, "the clients wants to...", but instead of data noise you could provide a richer query option in your GUI.

Comment: Have you normalized your tables? A part of your problem maybe poorly created tables.

Comment: @kumar - what sort of data do you have in there? If there are images or large data, then retrieving all would definitely take time & server resources. 3000 records is not a lot. Also, try running the query directly on sql server, how long does it take?

Comment: Please post schema and query. Without this impossible to answer. 3,000 rows is not a lot, it's tiny.

Comment: Have you actually narrowed it down to the query - have you considered that it may be the UI rendering that is taking time?

Answer (score 1):

It is essential to port your SQL query here for this question but assuming simple select statement my answers would be

1) First select the limited number of columns that are required. Don't use `Select *`. Use specific columns if all columns are not required in your desired output

2) If your select statement has a filter then use the filter in such an order that it does the minimum number of operations and gets the optimum result (if you post SQL statements then I can surely help on this)

3) Create an index for the specific field that will also help to improve your query performance

Hope this helps

Comment: Even he wants all the fields he should not use select * , because the DB need to search which columns are part of the table in another table . (Even if its indexed it is quite not as performant as naming directly the columns)

Comment: @pastjean, According to Microsoft that is not true: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/transactsql/thread/7159db49-50ff-4784-9e5b-7344bbacdcc6

Comment: @tster , it is said tough it is bad practice and the server as to do column resolution but it is not a big performance hit : say 0.01ms on a 10ms query

Comment: @pastjean, likely the column meta-data is already in memory.  And even if you give the column names it still has to look up the meta-data because it has to know where in the tuples the data will be arranged and what the type of the data is.

Answer (score 0):

Since you don't want to show all 3000 records at one time, use paging in your SQL statement.  Here is an example using the AdventureWorks database in SQL Server.  Assuming each of your webpage shows 25 records, this statement will get all records required in the 5th page.  The "QueryResults" is a Common Table Expression (CTE) and I only get the primary keys to keep the CTE small in case you had millions of records.  Afterwards, I join the QueryResult (CTE) to the main table (Product) and get any columns I need.  @PageNumber below is the current page number.  Perform your "WHERE" and sort statements within the CTE.

```
DECLARE @PageNumber int, @PageSize int;
SET @PageSize = 25;
SET @PageNumber = 5;

; WITH QueryResults AS
(
    SELECT TOP (@PageSize * @PageNumber) ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ProductID) AS ROW,
    P.ProductID
    FROM Production.Product P WITH (NOLOCK)
)
SELECT QR.ROW, QR.ProductID, P.Name
FROM QueryResults QR WITH (NOLOCK)
INNER JOIN Production.Product P WITH (NOLOCK) ON QR.ProductID = P.ProductID
WHERE ROW BETWEEN (((@PageNumber - 1) * @PageSize) + 1) AND (@PageSize * @PageNumber)
ORDER BY QR.ROW ASC
```

Answer (score 0):

3000 records is not a big deal for SQL Server 2008 you just need to:-

1. avoid * in a select statement.
2. proper indexing is needed, you my try include column
3. try to use index on primary as well as foreign key columns

and you can also try query in different way as same query can be written in different way and the compare both query cost and setting time statistics on.